# Update a specific attribute based on another attribute of a product

Tags: product, attributes, database-update

I have a attribute named vendor_cost and another named original_vendor_cost.
I want to update some of my product (let's say if they have id 1,2, or 3 ) and set their [ vendor_cost ] to [ original_vendor_cost * 1.3 ].
here is my code:

```
$attributesData = array("original_vendor_cost"=>"WHAT SHOULD BE HERE?");
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action')->updateAttributes(
                                                   array(1,2,3,...,n),
                                                   $attributesData,
                                                   Mage::app()->getStore()
                                              );
```

As in plain SQL we say:

`UPDATE table_name SET vendor_cost = original_vendor_cost*1.3 WHERE id IN (1,2,3,...,n)`

I know I can use a `foreach()` and get original_vendor_cost value and calculate new value for vendor_cost one by one and so on, But assuming the amount of my product for update(n) could be more than 10000, this is absolutely not an option, because it may take a long time to process and a big amount of queries to my database.